# Eclipse PDT not supporting php code completion

Tags: php, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-pdt

I have eclipse pdt europa version. Its not supporting php code completion in php files. Anybody tell me how to enable this.

Comment: Eclipse Europa is an Eclipse 3.3 released in 2007, 7 years ago. Any chance you could try PDT with a more recent one?

Comment: is it..!! Omg, Which version is new?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29: Kepler 4.3, but Luna (4.4) will be released in a few days.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, the first test to do is check if [Eclipse PDT plugin](http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.pdt) works better with a more recent Eclipse version.

As see in the [Eclipse wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29), Eclipse Europa is Eclipse 3.3 released in 2007, 7 years ago.

The [Eclipse download](http://www.eclipse.org/epsilon/download/) page list Eclipse Kepler (4.3) and will propose Eclipse Luna (4.4) in a few days (end June 2014).

> PDT 3.x can be easily added to an existing Eclipse installation via the Juno repository.

You can try [PDT 3.3](http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.pdt/releases/3.3).